# How to map the following properties?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

```java
public class Car {

    // fields
   private String type;
   private String model;
   private String color;
}
```

```java
public class Property {

private String propertyName;
private String propertyVal;

}
```

so  I have the following mapping method

```java
 private List<Property> mapCarProperties(Car car) {

         List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>();
        Property type = new Property();
        streetAddressLine1Text.setPropertyName("type");
        streetAddressLine1Text.setPropertyValue(car.getType());

        Property modelValue = new Property();
        modelValue.setPropertyName("modelValue");
        modelValue.setPropertyValue(car.getModel());

        Property colorType = new Property();
        colorType.setPropertyName("colorType");
        colorType.setPropertyValue(car.getColor());

  properties.add(type);
  properties.add(modelValue);
  properties.add(colorType);
  
  return properties;
  
  }
```

everything works fine and now I have to add additional fields to Car class and map the same way as in the above mapping method. But after I do that, the method might look very lengthy and some reason I am not liking it, so just wondering if there is a better way to map even may be by using a framework such as Mapstruct? ready to learn and implement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Reflection for that. Following method will solve your problem.

```
private List<Property> mapCarProperties(Car car) {
    Field[] fields = car.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>();

    //Create list of property
    for ( Field field : fields  ) {
    try {
      Property prop = new Property();
      prop.setPropertyName( field.getName() );
      
      prop.setPropertyValue(field.get(car));
      properties.add(prop);

      } catch ( IllegalAccessException ex ) {
        log.error(ex);
    }
    return properties;
}
```

Now you can add N number of new variables and you don't need to change method.